# syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end '; else ^

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, syntax

Job#new

```
<ul>
<% if current_user.jobs.any? %>
<% current_user.jobs.each do |job| %>
<li> Job ID: <%= job.id %> Recipient: <%= job.recipient %> </li>
<% else %>
<%= "You have no jobs" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: try ending the `.each do` block before `else`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it:

```
<ul>
<% if current_user.jobs.any? %>
  <% current_user.jobs.each do |job| %>
    <li> Job ID: <%= job.id %> Recipient: <%= job.recipient %> </li>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= "You have no jobs" %>
<% end %>
```

You are opening an `each` and forget close `else` before